# how to return the error code when mocking a recvmsg function?

Tags: c, googletest, googlemock

I am using google test and google mock to test some C code:

```
struct msghdr message;
int retval;

retval = recvmsg(fd,&message,0);

if(retval == EINTR || retval == EAGAIN)
{
    // do something here
}
```

in my mock file, I mocked the `recvmsg` function:

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD3(recvmsg, int(int fd, struct msghdr *msg, int flags));
```

but how to set the `errno` as EINTR or `EAGAIN` when I set the return value of the mock function `recvmsg` as -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard action called `SetErrnoAndReturn(errnum, value)` which is described in [Google Mock docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#side-effects).

Comment: Correct function: SetErrnoAndReturn

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock free functions, but only class virtual member functions.

The proposed solution to mock free functions in [the docs](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions) is to define an interface exporting a virtual member function with the same signature as the free function. Then define an implementation that wraps up the call to the free function for production code and a mock for testing. So if your testing code is pure C, it won't be a solution for you.